# create xml without namespace

Tags: xml, groovy

I try to create XML  using

```
def builder = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder()
builder.encoding = "UTF-8"
def person = {
    mkp.xmlDeclaration()
    //mkp.declareNamespace('location':'http://someOtherNamespace')
    person(id:100){
        firstname("Jane")
        lastname("Doe")
        location.address("123 Main")
    }
}
println builder.bind(person)
```

I got this error:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Namespace prefix: location is not bound to a URI
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Namespace prefix: location is not bound to a URI
    at MyTest$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall(MyTest.groovy:9)
    at MyTest$_run_closure1.doCall(MyTest.groovy:6)
    at MyTest.run(MyTest.groovy:12)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

I don't need namespace. I need only declaration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends what you want your XML to look like (you don't say in your question):

If you want:

```
<location><address>123 Main</address></location>
```

Then change `location.address("123 Main")` to:

```
   location {
      address("123 Main")
   }
```

If you want:

```
<location address='123 Main'/>
```

Then change it to:

```
   location( address:"123 Main" )
```

Comment: then mark his reply as the answer: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/